# How to use django channel and celery to send messages regularly?

Tags: django, celery, channel

Below are my consumer code and tasks code. I want the task to start when the first user opens the page and establishes a channel, which begins querying data and periodically broadcasting to the corresponding group's channel. When subsequent users create channels, there is no need to start new tasks again. I have considered making the Celery task a scheduled task that broadcasts to the specified group's channel regardless of whether any user has opened the channel or not. However, I am not sure if this is a good solution.

```
# consumers.py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from app_monitor.tasks import monitor


class MonitorConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        self.group = 'monitor'

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.group, self.channel_name)
        monitor.delay(self.group)
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.group, self.channel_name)

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

    async def send_data(self, event):
        print(event)
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({"data": event['data']}))
```

```
# tasks.py
from dbaOps.celery import app
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from django.db import connections
from app_monitor.utils.sqlarea import MONITOR_SQL


@app.task
def monitor(group):
    try:
        with connections['tools'].cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(MONITOR_SQL)
            data = cur.fetchall()
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(group, {'type': 'send.data', 'data': data})
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: can you tell what problem are you facing with your current code approach?

Comment: Whenever a user creates a connection, the celery task will be executed once. I hope that the celery task has nothing to do with the user connection. The user just creates a connection and waits to receive the message.

Comment: isn't that happening with your code?

Comment: I may not have expressed clearly, in my code a celery task is called every time a user creates a new connection. What I want is that celery is executed regularly, and then the result is broadcast to all users, instead of the user creating a connection, it will trigger a task execution

Comment: @Tony use celery schedule than celery task call base on " 'schedule': 2,  # Run every 2 seconds "